# Ubuntu connect the internt from anywhere?

Tags: connection

Just a question I might ask you something. I'm heading off on a vacation soon, so all in honest, as a new Ubuntu user, I have never connected the Internet anywhere else besides home. So would I be able to access the Internet anywhere else? If yes, do I have to check the wireless network to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Network manager will list the available networks and the security (or lack of security). You can connect to any network that is open (unsecured) or if you know the password. Most hotels / restaurants will give you an network and password.

Some networks then use a proxy, so you have to open firefox and you will be redirected to the log in page. Once you log in you will have access to all protocols.

You should have no more or less problems with Ubuntu then Windows.

Comment: "You should have no more or less problems with Ubuntu then Windows." This is a very true statement. As someone that travels a lot most locations have "free wifi" and it SUCKS. Some old router from the 90s that barely has signal. Ubuntu won't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine. The worst places will be hotspots that make you click a web page to continue on to the internet.

There are a few places that make you install a app. Those won't work at all.

Which ever you use I recommend getting a good VPN provider. I recommend [vyprVPN](http://www.goldenfrog.com/vyprvpn). This will help keep people out of your data. A lot of coffee shops will listen in and collect emails and what not for their mailing list. A good VPN helps avoid that.